# Dual-boot Ubuntu ans Windows 8.1

Tags: system-installation

Hello there people of the Linux community!

I want to try Linux out on my Toshiba satellite laptop computer.

I have the .iso file ready and a USB Thumb drive

My specs:
Windows 8.1
Intel Core i3
500GB HDD
Intel HD Graphics 3000

My PC did not come with Windows 8 pre-installed;
It had Windows 7 which I update to Windows 8 and then updated to Windows 8.1

How can I install Ubuntu?

(I haven't touched the partitions or anything)

Can I use WUBI?

Comment: RockingRocker - if you wish to accept an answer, please register an account - then click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request that your accounts are merged.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WUBI had some bugs,so please don't install it.Try to install ubuntu on your hard-disk and make it dualboot with windows.

See [*this*](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to create bootable Ubuntu usb disk.See [*this*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Install_Ubuntu_after_Windows) to make Ubuntu to dualboot with windows.